# Conversion of multiple bam to bed using bedtools from different directory

Tags: bash, sh

I am having multiple directories  under a path cd /home/vdas/ChIP-Seq/output/
Directory listing

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_12_O_319_K27ac
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_12_O_319_K27me3
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_12_O_319_K4me1
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_12_O_319_K4me3
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_12_O_319_input
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_13_O1_122_K27ac
drwxrwxrwx 3 vdas   DPT    7 Feb  2 10:41 S_13_O1_122_K27me3
```

Inside each of the directory there is a *.sorted.bam file. I want to write a bash script which will go inside each of the sample directory and run the below command

```
bedtools bamToBed -i input .bam > out.bed
```

I wrote a small bash script but it is not working. Can you tell me where am getting wrong

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#$ -N bam2bed
#$ -cwd
#$ -e err_bam2bed.log
#$ -o out_bam2bed.log
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -M xyz@gmail.com
#$ -m bea
#$ -l h_vmem=25G

cd /home/vdas/ChIP-Seq/output
for x in `ls S*/*.sorted.bam` ; do
    echo "print current:$x"
    bedtools bamToBed -i "$x" > "${x%.bam}.bed"
done
echo "done"
```

Where am I getting it wrong. I do not intend to write over-repeating commands so what should be the exact way to create the for-loop. If am not wrong this should be fine. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cd /home/vdas/ChIP-Seq/output
for x in S*/*.sorted.bam ; do
    echo "print current:$x";
    bedtools bamToBed -i "$x" > "${x%.bam}.bed";
done
echo "done"
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, the bamToBed is installed in the root so I just changed to `bamToBed -i "$x" > "${x%.bam}.bed"` . It seems to work.